How to get all FreeIPA domain user attributes via LDAP access
I have problems getting all FreeIPA domain user attributes from LDAP. The thing is that ldapsearch and ipa user-show only provide non-empty attributes, and I need to find a way to get all the user's attributes. I am writing a script in Python with the ldap3 library, below is an example of the script and its result. Making sure the empty attributes helped the ldap browser, but how it was able to get them I couldn't figure out. Basic ldapsearch commands didn't help with any arguments.
Here is my code:
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, SUBTREE, ALL_ATTRIBUTES


ldap_server = 'ldap://$my_server$'
ldap_user = 'uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=$my_dc$,dc=local'
ldap_password = '$my_pass$'
base_dn = 'cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=$my_dc$,dc=local' 


server = Server(ldap_server, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user=ldap_user, password=ldap_password, auto_bind=True)

search_filter = '(uid=admin)'
conn.search(search_base=base_dn, search_filter=search_filter, search_scope=SUBTREE, attributes=['*'])


if conn.entries:
    user = conn.entries[0]
    print(f"User DN: {user.entry_dn}")
    for attribute in user.entry_attributes:
        print(f"{attribute}: {user[attribute]}")
else:
    print("User not found")


conn.unbind()

And the most interesting thing is that if you explicitly access an empty attribute by specifying attributes=['$my_attr$'], this script will return the entry $my_attr$: []

The attributes of a given LDAP object are given by the entry's objectClass. They are usually many classes for any given object, like person and inetOrgPerson.
Those object classes make up the directory schema which you can query at the root of the tree, the rootDSE. I don't know of a way to for the server to return empty attributes. There might be a control for that, but this algorithm should work with most directories:
On an authenticated connection with the sufficient rights:

Query the directory with a null search base and (objectClass=*)
Find the object class you care about.
Save the attributes of that class.
Query the object and list its attributes like you already do
For each attribute in the schema not in the ones returned, do ... something

Things to think about:

You might have to look at (dn: cn=schema). I cannot test, but try the above steps with your LDAP browser to be sure
Each object can have multiple objectClass and administrators can define their own. You can cache a copy of the schema, but keep it fresh
A given attribute can have multiple values, YMMV depending on what you intended to do


thank you for your answer and attention to the question, unfortunately it turned out that LDAP is really not intended for unloading empty attributes, I had to list them manually and request them in the queue.

Yes, that's what you need to do. My answer is about getting the list of those attributes dynamically (based on the objectClasses of the object your search found).

I would recommend to use FreeIPA API:
from ipalib import api 
import pprint

api.bootstrap(context="custom", in_server=True) 
api.finalize()

if api.env.in_server:
    api.Backend.ldap2.connect() 
else:
    api.Backend.rpcclient.connect()

data = api.Command.user_show("admin", all=True) 
pprint.pprint(data)

You need a valid Kerberos ticket before you can run the script:
$ echo $ADMIN_PASSWORD | kinit admin

